# How to get first name and last name and birthday... from Google authentication in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

I want to get the First name ,last name, gender and birthdate of the current user when he signin with google. FirebaseUser object do not give me first name and last name separated, gender and birthdate.
Any help.

Comment: Please share the part of your code where you sign in the user with Google.

Comment: @PeterKoltai I don't think the answer related to my code its a question not a problem . Hope you understand ,Thanks btw.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've signed in successfully with a google credential, you can grab any details pertaining to that user's account using the FirebaseUser object. Check out firebase's documentation on how to get and use that object. Be sure to keep in mind that the user could have those values set to null, however.

Documentation for using Flutter and FirebaseAuth: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/overview

Comment: Thanks , but I know all this , FirebaseUser object gives you full name and email just a bit of information about gmail user I want information like gender and first name and last name separeted ...

Comment: You cannot pull that from a google login using the FirebaseAuth package. The only information you can pull is that which gets synced to the FirebaseUser object.

Comment: Yes I know I can not get that from FirebaseUser object but is there a way to get them.

Comment: You need to go back and clarify your question further and provide more details on what you have already tried. Please read HowTo article on how to write a question on StackOverflow.